# VSCode Intellisense does not work with webpack + alias

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a project using babel alias:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js',
      '@cmp': resolve('src/components'),
      '@service': resolve('src/services'),
      '@scss': resolve('src/assets/styles'),
  }
}
```

and a component with:

```
import someService from '@service/some'
```

And the Intellisense does not work.
with:

```
import someService from '../../../../service/some'
```

It does.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try creating a [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson) and configuring the `paths` compiler options

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "paths": {
      "@cmp/*": ["./src/components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information about `paths` and other compiler options [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

Comment: Great solution!  

FWIW this solution is not specific to webpack and works great for any* vscode project.  *Ones I've tried, especially React-Native.

Comment: @Johan It works, but eslint is complaining about it: _Unable to resolve path to module '@components/SocialMedia'.eslint(import/no-unresolved)_ What can I do to get rid of this? I still want eslint to warn me about unresolved paths.

Comment: @cbdev420 I don't remember doing anything specific to my eslint config.  I did set my `module` to `es6` though.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me, as suggested [here](https://medium.com/@justintulk/solve-module-import-aliasing-for-webpack-jest-and-vscode-74007ce4adc9) (I wanted `@/` to resolve to `./src/`):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

Minimal version, but I'd leave `exclude` too:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Matt's answer, in a TypeScript project you don't need to create a `jsconfig.json` file, you can simply add it to your `tsconfig.json` file and vscode picks it up.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    ...
        "paths": {
            "@MyAlias/*": ["./myDirectrory/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to get IntelliSense working for resolving directly from `src` like with your webpack config.

Ie.

```
import Requests from 'utils/requests';
```

and that file lives at `src/utils/requests.js`

...

```
# jsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

```
# webpack.config.js

  resolve: {
    symlinks: false,
    modules: [
      path.resolve('./src'),
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },
```