# eslint resolve error on imports using with path mapping configured jsconfig.json

Tags: javascript, eslint, visual-studio-code, eslintrc

Here's my project structure:

```
-src

--assets
--components
--constants
--helpers
--pages
--routes

eslintrc.json
jsconfig.json
App.js
index.js
```

I was tired of:

`import SomeComponent from '../../../../../components/SomeComponent';`

And I wanted to do:

`import SomeComponent from '@components/SomeComponent';`

So I saw this question here on SO:

[VSCode Intellisense does not work with webpack + alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181037/vscode-intellisense-does-not-work-with-webpack-alias)

And I got it to work with:

**jsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"]
     }
  }
}
```

But eslint now it's complaining that it's unresolved, even though it compiles just fine.

**eslint error:**

> Unable to resolve path to module '@components/SocialMedia'.eslint(import/no-unresolved)

**NOTE:**

I don't want to disable eslint. I want to make it understand this kind of path too.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

An alternative way, assuming that you have `eslint-plugin-import` installed (in your devDependencies). Just add this "settings" in your `.eslintrc.json` file.

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src/"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**jsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Then you can just call the

```
import SomeComponent from 'components/SomeComponent';`
```

Comment: This solution works for files within src. However eslint could not resolve path for files at root. How can that be resolved?

Comment: Seems like eslint and jsconfig should play nicely together so you don't need to do this but maybe I am not fully grasping the purpose of jsconfig. Your answer worked for me, thank you!

Comment: This works, but I lose `⌘ +click` i.e. goto definition feature which is what I mostly use for hopping across files. Any suggestions? (I am also not on a TS Project)

Comment: @StangSpree you can do `moduleDirectory: ['node_modules', './']`, but now you need to add a `src` prefix to import the same component in the above example.

Answer (score 22):

I have installed:

`npm install -D eslint-import-resolver-alias`

And I added to my eslint config file:

**eslintrc.json**

```
"settings": {
    "import/resolver" : {
      "alias" : {
        "map" : [
          ["@components","./src/components/"]
        ],
        "extensions": [".js"]
      }
    }
  }
```

And now it's working and eslint is not showing errors anymore.

**EDIT:**

I'm using webpack and I also needed to do:

**webpack.config.js**

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/')
    }
  }
```

Comment: This solution works for files within src. However eslint could not resolve path for files at root. How can that be resolved?

Answer (score 5):

for lerna users:

eslintrc

```
{
  "settings": {
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        // this resolves path alias import problems
        "moduleDirectory": [ "apps/*/src", "packages/*/src" ]
      },
      "typescript": {
        "alwaysTryTypes": true,
        // this resolves packages import problems
        "project": [
          "packages/*/tsconfig.json", 
          "apps/*/tsconfig.json"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```